# Continuity of $f(x,y)=|x|^y$ at $(0,0)$

Tags: calculus, limits

Can $$f(x,y)=|x|^y$$ be appropriately defined at (0,0) to be continuous there?

How to check if $\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}|x|^y $ exists in this case?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have $f(x,x)\to 1$ and $f(0,y)\to 0$ so it cannot be continuous at $(0,0)$ because the value depends on the path you choose for studying the limit.